# What's the difference between OpenCV's BRIEF and rBRIEF in tod_*?

Tags: ros, object-recognition, tod-detecting, tod-training

[image: Rosanswers logo]

OpenCV implements the BRIEF descriptor as described in *"BRIEF: Binary Robust Independent Elementary Features"* (ECCV 2010). It's called `cv::BriefDescriptorExtractor`. ROS packages `tod_training` and `tod_detecting` have an own implementation called tod::RBriefDescriptorExtractor. I wonder where's the difference. Is there any publication I have missed?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9918/what%27s-the-difference-between-opencv%27s-brief-and-rbrief-in-tod_*?/) by [Julius](https://answers.ros.org/users/252/julius/) on ROS Answers with karma: 960 on 2011-05-08

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Julius](https://answers.ros.org/users/252/julius/) on 2011-06-04**:
I now think the "r" stands for "Rotation" (backed up by a glance at the source code), and BRIEF as it is originally described in the paper is not designed to produce rotation-invariant features. So, this indicates the modification to incorporate rotation-invariance. Needs to be confirmed, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

rBRIEF was a modified BRIEF. It has proven to be insufficient and was replaced by a new descriptor (ORB) that will be detailed in OpenCV 2.3 due on Monday June 20th, 2011

---

Originally posted by [Vincent Rabaud](https://answers.ros.org/users/358/vincent-rabaud/) with karma: 1111 on 2011-06-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Julius](https://answers.ros.org/users/252/julius/) on 2011-06-21**:
Thanks. Looking forward to the corresponding paper. ORB can also be used from OpenCV trunk (I know that rev 5465 works).